# Sending cron output as a text file attachment

Tags: linux, cron, attachment, email

I sysadmin a multiplayer game at CentOS 6.5 Linux server for a customer.

The customer has requested me to send the daily chat logs (to identify and ban agressive players) - as a text file attachement.

So I have come up with the following crontab command:

```
CONTENT_TYPE="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
MAILFROM=First.Last@gmail.com
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    command

55      23      *       *       *       
grep CHAT /var/log/game-`date +\%a`-*.txt | 
(echo 'The log is attached'; uuencode `date +\%A`.txt) | 
mail -s 'The daily chat log' First.Last@yandex.ru
```

This works well for me with Gmail. But the customer is only using Mail.ru or Yandex.ru accounts and there it looks bad - no attachment is shown and he sees the *uuencode* output inline (aka `begin 664 MT)Blah§$%&Blah`):

[image: Yandex mail screenshot]

**My question is** if there is a safer way to send a cron job output by mail **as a text file attachment**. I know that a lot can be done with the help of perl (and I can program it), but I wonder if there is an easier way - with *uuencode* or *mailx* or some other utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mailx` has the `-a <filename>` switch to add attachments. And on CentOS 6 by default `/bin/mail` is already  mailx.

Comment: +1 thanks. I've noticed that too, but I have a STDOUT from *grep* here and not a file. Should I redirect it to a temp file or is there maybe some nice trick (like using `-` as a pseudo filename)?

Comment: Indeed convert the cron entry to call a simple shell script that creates the temporary file, sends a mail message with the report as attachment and then removes the temp file. Posting here takes longer than writing the script. Possibly since you have a temp file  include some stats in message body as well,